# How to prevent Chrome from erasing History

Tags: google-chrome, history

My laptop is running Windows 10 (upgraded from Windows 8.1). I have visited many websites to find out the answer for this question: Why does my laptop erase all these websites from browser (Chrome) as soon as I shut down my laptop or when restart it?
I have checked the settings and made some changes, but still nothing changed.

Comment: In settings is the answer.  Must be something you're missing.  Check cookies too. If your unfamiliar with advanced settings you can just reinstall Chrome too.

Comment: Also, verify that you aren't operating in incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

- Go in Google Chrome's Settings
- Click Show advanced settings
- In the Privacy section, click Content Settings
- In the Cookies section, verify that `Allow local data to be set` is chosen and `Block third-party cookies and site data` is unchecked

It seems like your browser is currently set to `Keep local data until you quit your browser`.